# promise based programming, possible or not?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, promise

i've learn many about promises with your guides, friends
but a question is created in my mind after learning [promise](/questions/tagged/promise):

is it true(possible) to build whole [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) project only with promises?
if not: where is [callback](/questions/tagged/callback) more useful than promise?

Comment: no, because the majority of "built-in" node functions don't use Promises ... note: Promises can't work without the notion of a callback either

Comment: A promisified function actually is a plain function that returns a Promise object, and almost all native javascript functions are plain functions, then how it is possible?
Callback doesn't mean it will be invoked asynchronously, sometimes it;s just a dependency injection (or IoC) design, e.g., many Array, String methods need a callback function, but they called it synchronously.

Comment: Promises are great for some types of notifications.  But, they have a narrowly defined set of requirements for them to be a fit (notify once and only once, must fit into a pending => resolved or pending => rejected model, are not synchronous, etc...).  So, I'd say use them for all async operations that fit into the above model, but use EventEmitters or regular callbacks or other publish/subscribe models for other types of notifications.  See [When to use Promises vs Callbacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041462/node-js-when-to-use-promises-vs-callbacks/45046393) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

1. A promisified function actually is a plain function that returns a Promise object, and almost all native javascript and built-in node.js functions are plain functions, then how it is possible?
2. Callback function doesn't mean it will be invoked asynchronously, sometimes it's just a dependency injection (or IoC) design, e.g., many Array, String methods need a callback function, but they called it synchronously, while Promise is a asynchronous mechanism.