# Best practice for writing promises and when to promise or callback?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to understand promises and from what I can understand, there are numerous way of using them. When do I use a promise and when do I use a callback like in the example below? I would like to know the difference here, since from what I can tell, they do pretty much the same job in this example.

## 1

```
await req.session.destroy().promise().then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

## 2

```
req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) {
       console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('Session successfully destroyed');
   }
});
```

Comment: There are no promises in the second example

Comment: The second one is actually a callback-pattern and not a promise-pattern.

Comment: I see that now, stupid of me. However, my question still stand, since from what I can tell they do the same job correct?

Comment: They do the same job. Callbacks are the traditional approach. I think most new/updated libraries now at least try to employ the promise-pattern.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45041462/node-js-when-to-use-promises-vs-callbacks

Comment: question is now updated

Comment: Best practice? When they do the same job, always use the promise.